# Placing new text on top of older text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried this a couple of ways and I seem to be missing something simple.  What I want is when the user enters their input (ie. Take Sword) the output ("You now have a sword") appears on top of the last output.

So if your first 2 commands were:

1. Go East
2. Go South

Then your output would appear as:

1. You Are now in the SOUTH room.
2. You are now in the EAST room.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
var input = $("#commandLine").val();
$("#placeholder").prepend($("<span class='line'>" + "</span>"));
```

I've tried multiple things on this line:

`$("#placeholder").prepend($("<span class='line'>" + "</span>"));`

to include `input` and `$("#commandLine").val()`

Both of those create 2 problems:

1. It takes whatever I type (go east) and displays it on the page IN ADDITION to the output (Go east.  You are now in the EAST room).
2. While the input stuff I don't want properly stacks, the output stuff I DO want does not.  (ie. each new output goes below not above the previous output).

I hope that makes sense.  Here is a fiddle of what I have:  https://jsfiddle.net/megler/a1fjd5gd/9/

For some reason, I can't get the fiddle to run correctly, but the code is working locally for me.

I know that input and $("#commandLine...") are incorrect, but I don't know what to put in it's place to pull the output of the later functions.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

I need "go east" and "take sword" to go away and the lines above that to switch in order.

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: you missed + after input at line nbr 5 in your jsfiddel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You've got a syntax error in your fiddle. Line 5:

```
$("#placeholder").prepend($("<span class='line'>" + input "</span>"));
```

should be:

```
$("#placeholder").prepend($("<span class='line'>" + input + "</span>"));
```

Here is an [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1fjd5gd/6/)

Second: Your travel function is missing variables.

```
var travel = function(direction) {
    var newRoom = rooms[currentRoom.paths[direction]];
    if (!newRoom) {
        $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();
    }
    else {
        currentRoom = newRoom;
        $("<p>You are now in the " + currentRoom.name + " Room.</p>").properDisplay();
    }
};
```

This function doesn't have a `rooms` variable or a `currentRoom` variable. You're going to need to define those somewhere for that function to work correctly.

Third: I added a new div `#actions` that will allow you to use a `properDisplay()` function like this:

```
$.fn.properDisplay = function() {
    return $("#actions").prepend(this).fadeIn(1000);
    // return this.hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
};
```

For your fade effect as well:

```
return $("#actions").prepend(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1fjd5gd/12/

Updated:

```
$.fn.properDisplay = function() {
    this.addClass("line");
    return $("#actions").prepend(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
};
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1fjd5gd/14/

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long day.  I have those variables in another file.  Here's the updated fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/megler/a1fjd5gd/9/

Comment: This appears to be what you're looking for. Check updated fiddle at the bottom.

Comment: Agreed.  It is.  By doing this, I lost the fade effect in the text.  So 2 questions:

1.  Can I just delete this line `$("#col1").prepend($("<span class='line'>" +  "</span>"));` from line 6?

2.  how do I insert `"<span class='line'>" +  "</span>"`  to regain the fadeout?

Comment: Added a little code at the bottom of my post for your fadeout. Updated the fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/a1fjd5gd/13/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't communicate that properly.  Check the CSS on the code.  The idea is as the text scrolls down the page, the slowly fades from view.  that's what the `"<span class='line'>" +  "</span>"` accomplishes.  I wasn't sure how to reinsert that with the new fix.

Comment: Updated fiddle at bottom of the answer. You've still got a bit of a bug with your styling ... after "5" items ... you don't get the effect you want. One solution .... start removing DOM elements after that 5th item. Or you could use CSS overflow so that you get a scrollbar that hides the items below a specific height.

Comment: Thanks @BryanRay!  That does EXACTLY what I was trying to do.  I knew I'd have to fiddle with the CSS more to get the effect to go lower, but at least it's now all moving in the right direction and fading out.  Many many thanks!   May I ask,what was the purpose of adding th enew div?  I followed everything else you did but that.

Comment: Adding the new div basically allows you to "store" certain elements in a specific spot. This allows you to ignore anything else that is "outside" that div, making it easier to leverage jQuery's append and prepend functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you replace the

```
$("#placeholder").prepend();
```

by

```
$("#col1").prepend();
```

the output will properly stack up above the previous info displayed.

Comment: Tried that, @DamienDUPRAZ.  Still performs the same.  Currently, I have it at ` $("#col1").prepend($("<span class='line'>" +  "</span>"));`  That removes the input, but the output still goes in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

What about that fiddle ?

I changed the properDisplay method with the following

```
$.fn.properDisplay = function() {
    $("#col1").prepend(this);
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    return true;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a1fjd5gd/11/

Comment: No, that has the same outcome.  It shows your commands (go south, take sword), but not the outcome (You now have a sword...).  Your answer is very close to @BryanRay.  I'm not sure why his works and yours does not.  I see he added a new div.  Maybe that's why.